# Error en un return

Tags: java

El return del metodo raiz me da un error y no se a que se debe

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaizCuadrada {
private int numero;

//CONSTRUCTORES

public RaizCuadrada(){
    System.out.println("Inroduce un numero: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    numero=sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
}

//SET AND GET

public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

//METODOS

public double raiz() {
    double respuesta;
    if(numero > 0) {
        respuesta = Math.sqrt(numero);
    }else {
        System.out.println("El numero introducido es negativo");
    }
    return respuesta;
}

}
```

Comment: Que error te da . ?

Comment: The local variable respuesta may not have been initialized

Comment: Hazte la pregunta siguiente: si `numero` es negativo, ¿qué valor le asignas a `respuesta` antes de hacer el `return`? El compilador notó esto y te está avisando que probablemente tienes un defecto en tu lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta de IDE

> La respuesta de la variable local puede no haberse inicializado

lo que te da a entender que al declararla sin asignarle valor ,

> double respuesta;

te podria generar defectos , te recomiendo asiglarle -1 para saber que si te llega ese valor es porque es "false" podrias usarlo como bandera

```
public double raiz() {
    double respuesta = -1;
    if(numero > 0) {
        respuesta = Math.sqrt(numero);
    }else {
        System.out.println("El numero introducido es negativo");
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```